# Is Kafka message headers the right place to put event type name?

Tags: apache-kafka

In scenario where multiple single domain event types are produced to single topic and only subset of event types are consumed by consumer i need a good way to read the event type before taking action.
I see 2 options:

1. Put event type (example "ORDER_PUBLISHED") into message body (payload) itself which would be like broker agnostic approach and have other advantages. But would involve parsing of every message just to know the event type.
2. Utilize Kafka message headers which would allow to consume messages without extra payload parsing.

The context is event-sourcing. Small commands, small payloads. There are no huge bodies to parse. Golang. All messages are protobufs. gRPC.

What is typical workflow in such scenario.

I tried to google on this topic, but didn't found much on Headers use-cases and good practices.
Would be great to hear when and how to use Kafka message headers and when not to use.

Comment: I think the headers are meant to be generic anyway. There is no "recommendation" for how to use them, however, you still are required to parse this information to know how to handle the data, no?

Comment: Create a dedicated topic per event types. https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/

Comment: @JRibkr  The linked article says **DO NOT** create dedicated topics per event types. Multiple event types that apply to the same aggregate or entity should go in the same topic. That's necessary in order (excuse the pun) to process them in order. It also helps the application logic to follow the *logic centralization* design principle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly the same topic should be used for different event types that apply to the same entity/aggregate ([reference](https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/)). Example: BookingCreated, BookingConfirmed, BookingCancelled, etc. should all go to the same topic in order to (excuse the pun) guarantee ordering of delivery (in this case the booking ID is the message key).

When the consumer gets one of these events, it needs to identify the event type, parse the payload, and route to the processing logic accordingly. The **event type** is the piece of message **metadata** that allows this identification.

Thus, **I think a custom Kafka message header is the best place to indicate the type of event.** I'm not alone:

- [Felipe Dutra](https://medium.com/@felipedutratine/event-sourcing-best-practices-with-kafka-b80df41612eb): "Kafka allow you to put meta-data as header of your message. So use it to put information about the message, version, type, a correlationId. If you have chain of events, you can also add the correlationId of opentracing"
- This [GE ERP system](https://www.ge.com/digital/documentation/proficy-plant-applications/version82/r_kafka_topic_message_structure.html) has a header labeled "event-type" to show "The type of the event that is published" to a kafka topic (e.g., "ProcessOrderEvent").
- This [other solution](https://www.chirpstack.io/application-server/integrations/kafka/) mentions that "A header 'event' with the event type is included in each message"  in their Kafka integration.

Headers are new in Kafka. Also, as far as I've seen, Kafka books focus on the 17 thousand Kafka configuration options and Kafka topology. Unfortunately, we don't easily find much on how an event-driven architecture can be mapped with the proper semantics onto elements of the Kafka message broker.

Comment: Thank you for your time on writing this answer. This Q was quite old already and i work in a little bit different area now. But personally i also think that the headers is good option. Also... i could add argument against putting every message type in the separate topic - by doing so, you should start to worry about things like synchronized atomic clocks to get the message timestamps right. At certain message rates it becomes really important issue if every domain/entity event type goes into separate topics. To avoid these kind of problems it's better to use single topic.

Comment: M. Kleppmann in article https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/ says that... if you need an strong ordering guaranties, then you should consider single topic which is pretty much logical. Thus, the event type parsing should be implemented in the consumers. And if you should cherry pick the events by it's type (multiple consumers processing events) then parsing the every single message comes at processing cost. This why using message headers seems the most efficient way, but is less portable.

Comment: Yes, and indeed his article is the first reference I linked to. I just wish Kleppmann would have also covered good practices for differentiating the event types within a topic.